OpenIddict/OIDC Redirect to Auth Server on Logout
I created an OpenIddict auth server for my existing application which uses AspNetCore Identity. The login process works great, but I have an issue with the logout process. I want it to automatically redirect to the auth server login page on logout. Right now, the auth server returns the html for the login page but my app does not redirect. Here's my setup:
Startup.cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44395";
                options.ClientId = "myclient";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.Scope.Add(Scopes.Profile);
                options.Scope.Add(Scopes.Email);
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = Claims.Name
                };
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Account/Login";
            });

The Logout() method in my AccountController:
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            SignOut(authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = "/"
                });
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

The Startup of my auth server:
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection-dev"));
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
          .AddDefaultUI();

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigins",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .WithOrigins(
                            ["http://localhost:5000"])
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                       .UseDbContext<UserDbContext>();
            })
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("connect/authorize")
                   .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("connect/introspect")
                   .SetLogoutEndpointUris("connect/logout")
                   .SetTokenEndpointUris("connect/token")
                   .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("connect/userinfo")
                   .SetVerificationEndpointUris("connect/verify");

                options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                       .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                options.UseAspNetCore()
                       .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
            })
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
                options.UseLocalServer();
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });

And the AuthorizationController.Logout(): I removed the consent logout part so it should just log the user out right away.
[HttpGet("~/connect/logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return SignOut(
            authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            properties: new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "/"
            });
    }

The post_logout_redirect_uri is http://localhost:5000/signout-callback-oidc.
When I try to logout, it sends the following requests:

http://localhost:5000/Account/Logout redirects to
http://localhost:5000/ redirects to
https://localhost:44395/connect/authorize?client_id=angularclient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&code_challenge=jwmpTTxxxx (OPTIONS)
https://localhost:44395/connect/authorize?client_id=oodleangularclient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&code_challenge=jwmpTTxxx location: https://localhost:44395/Identity/Account/Login? redirects to


https://localhost:44395/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3Doodleangularclient%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5000%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%26code_challenge%3DjwmpTT (OPTIONS)
6. https://localhost:44395/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3Doodleangularclient%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5000%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%26code_challenge%3DjwmpTT  The response is the html login page of the auth server.
